# What is use of camel case in Eclipse Resource, Type Search

Tags: eclipse, camelcasing

Other than `wildcards,- *?` I can even go for `camel case`, it is slightly confusing, because when I searched some pattern,- I am getting mix of cases when dig into package and search, moreover results not had come as expected.

How do I effectively use `camel case` with or without wild card, paticularly searching within some specific package. What is this for `camel case` in Eclipse,- `Type & Resource`,- search.

Search term I have used,-

> com.sun.*pda

And result for it,-

[image]

For term,

> PD

Results are,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for Open Type says:

> The following pattern kinds are supported:
>
> Wildcards:
>
> - "*" for any string and "?" for any character
> - terminating "<" or " " (space) to prevent the automatic prefix matching, e.g. "java.*Access<" to match java.util.RandomAccess but not
>     java.security.AccessControlContext
>
> Camel case:
>
> - "TZ" for types containing "T" and "Z" as upper-case letters in camel-case notation, e.g. java.util.TimeZone
> - "NuPoEx" or "NuPo" for types containing "Nu", "Po", (and "Ex") as parts in camel-case notation, e.g. java.lang.NullPointerException
> - terminating "<" or " " (space) to fix the number of camel-case parts, e.g. "HMap<" and "HaMap<" match "HashMap" and "HatMapper", but
>     not "HashMapEntry" nor "Hashmap".

Comment: What about lower case, in place of `Camel Case`, its matching with mix and match of case. Is that it means or it is different as `Camel Case` considers only starting alphabet of terms that are Capitals in case of `class` from starting on-wards?

Comment: My understanding is that Lower case ignores case when matching. Upper case ignores all lower case when matching.